# Reading the payload data inside out sequence for binary relay in wso2esb 4.0.3

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

We have a proxy service(ESB 4.0.3) that reads from JMS queue (JMS 1.0) and calls a rest service .We are using binary relay for application/json using binary builder and formatter in axis2.xml

```
    <messageBuilder contentType="application/json"
                    class="org.wso2.carbon.relay.BinaryRelayBuilder"/>
    <messageFormatter contentType="application/json"
                      class="org.wso2.carbon.relay.ExpandingMessageFormatter"/>
```

This backend rest service returns an identifier and this has to be processed in the out sequence of the proxy service.Now the challenge here is to read the response which is a binary payload in the ESB sequence and capture that response identifier.

How to read the binary data in the out sequence of WSO2 ESB 4.0.3?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [builder](http://docs.wso2.org/wiki/display/ESB451/Builder+Mediator) mediator, which is used to build the message

Comment: I already built the binary message using the messagebuilder entry in the axi2.xml.My question was to read the binary message.There is an Identifier in the binary message out sequence. I need to read that identifier and sent it to REST service.

Comment: Basically binary data is unreadable. I need to get the identifier from the binary data payload.

Comment: Builder mediator is not as same as message builders and formatters mentioned in axis2.xml. If you use the builder mediator, it will build the soap message and then you will be able to read the identifier which you have mentioned. This should be used in the out sequence of your proxy.